# How can I remove all items from my array and display it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a mock webstore I'm making for a project and I can't seem to get my empty cart button working. The user clicks add or remove item to add or remove items from the cart, but my button to empty the cart isn't working.

```
<button type="button" onclick="removeAll()" style="color:black">Empty Cart</button>
```

I've tried removing each item individually with one button click but it only removed the first item in the array.

```
function removeItem(itemIndex) { //remove item from cart
cart.remove(itemIndex);
cart.display();
}

function removeAll(itemIndex) { //removes all items from cart
removeItem(0);
removeItem(1);
removeItem(2);
}

function Cart (holder, items) {
this.holder = holder;
this.items = items;
this.quantities = Array();
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
this.quantities[i] = 0;

this.add = function (index) {
this.quantities[index]++;
}
this.remove = function (index) {
if (this.quantities[index] > 0)
this.quantities[index]--;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: That structure looks...odd. Where does `items` come from? Why are `items` and `quantities` separate? Are they meant to be parallel arrays? (Parallel arrays are rarely a good design structure.)

Comment: If you call removeItem(0); it will only do this.quantities[0]--, it will not remove all the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that code, you want `removeAll` to be:

```
function removeAll() { //removes all items from cart
    var n;
    for (n = 0; n < cart.quantities.length; ++n) {
        cart.quantities[n] = 0;
    }
    cart.display();
}
```

...though it would probably make sense to put `removeAll` on `Cart.prototype` (adjusted accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just reset the array?

```
function removeAll() {
    this.items = [];
    this.quantities = [];
}
```

Comment: For one thing, apparently `quantities` needs to have entries (with the value 0) for each of the entries in `items`. *Edit:* Re your edit, it looks like `items` is never added to/removed from in the original code.

Comment: Not looking at the code in the question, no. It clears out `items`, which doesn't appear to be meant to change.

Comment: Logically, why would you "empty cart" by resetting quantities? Wouldnt it make more sense to actually 'empty' the cart? Given thats what he seems to be trying to achieve, not reset the quantities to 0;

Comment: I suggest looking again at the code in the question. (And yes, the use of `items` seems odd; I flagged that up in a question on the question some time back.) But the code is clear that `items` is not modified while `quantities` is.